# Why is 蜀 composed of net (网), packag(ed) (裹) and insect (虫)?

Tags: meaning, characters

蜀 has three components:

- 罒 - 网
- 勹 - 裹
- 虫

How the kingdom of Shu become a wrapped bug in a net?

Comment: This decomposition is not correct. 罒 and 勹 is one unit, and is the [original form of 視](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2820). [蜀 is 視 + 虫](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=3233), as given by Western Zhou oracle bones, but the combined meaning is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

蜀漢領土主要在蜀地，故把它稱為「蜀國」。
蜀地最早是「古蜀國」。
開國之王名為「蠶叢」，他是位養蠶專家。
他為了養蠶事業到成都居住，因而建立了「古蜀國」。
這就是為什麼蜀漢之名會和蠶有關的原因。

The territory of 蜀漢 was mainly in 蜀地, so it was called 蜀國.
The first country in 蜀地 was 古蜀國.
The founder's name was 蠶叢, he was an expert in sericulture.
He moved to Chengdu for his sericulture, and thus established the 古蜀國.
This is why the name of 蜀漢 is related to silkworms.

Source: wikipedia

Answer (score 3):

说文解字 http://www.zdic.net/z/23/sw/8700.htm

> 【卷十三】【虫部】
>
> **蜀**: *葵中蠶也。从虫，上目象蜀頭形，中象其身蜎蜎。《詩》曰：“蜎蜎者蜀。”市玉切*

Translation:

> 蜀- Silk worm in sunflower [虫 Radical]
>
> 目 on top represents Silk worm's head,
>
> 勹 in the middle represents silk worm wiggling
>
> 虫 is the radical to indicate 蜀 is related to worm/bug/insect

[image]

It was also a region's name

> 古蜀国的历史(History of old Shǔ region) https://www.zhihu.com/question/27890526
>
> *黄帝之子昌意娶**蜀山氏**女 (The son of the Yellow Emperor Chang Yi married the daughter of the **Shushan** clan)*

蜀山 was a family name that named after a mountain

> In the same article, it stated the first nation in the Shǔ region was founded by 蠶叢 about 34,000 years ago-- an ancient time that written language had not been created yet. The written term 蜀地 (Shu region) might be named after him in later years.

Answer (score 1):

Current archeology finds 蜀 in oracle bone script. Actually it is combination of 目 (eye. a vertical eye), 人 (human) and 虫 (insect like animal).

[image]

蜀 was the name of an ancient kingdom at the time of the empire of 商. This character depicts the founder (蠶叢) of ancient 蜀 kingdom who was famous for the breeding of silkworm.

[image]

The ancient kingdom produced some great bronze works with emphasis on the eyes.

In this way, we know that:

```
目 : The emphasis on eyes in ancient 蜀 culture.
人 : The people of 蜀
虫 : The silkworm of 蜀
```

蜀, is the characteristics of some people who emphasized on eyes and bred silkworm. The character 蜀 is still a geographic term referring to 四川, the location of the ancient kingdom.